# Why can't I access the HttpContext from the Controller initializer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller set up like this:

```
public class GenesisController : Controller
{

    private string master;
    public string Master { get { return master; } }

    public GenesisController()
    {
        bool mobile = this.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice; // this line errors
        if (mobile)
            master="mobile";
        else
            master="site";
    }

}
```

All of my other controllers inherit from this GenesisController. Whenever I run the application, i get this error saying

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can I access HttpContext and from the controller initialization?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the HttpContext is not available in the controller constructor. You could override the Initialize method where it will be accessible, like this:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    bool mobile = this.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice; // this line errors
    if (mobile)
        master="mobile";
    else
        master="site";
}
```

Also I bet that what you are trying to do with this master variable and booleans might be solved in a [far more elegant way](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) than having your controllers worry about stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Scott Hanselman's article. At first I was thinking his approach was far too complex and a bit overkill... but after working with my appraoch a realized all the different scenarios that would need to be considered.

For now, i've got it working my way. But, when I revisit this for live sites I'll probably follow Scott's article.